# ディクショナリの要素数の出現回数カウント

Tags: python

pythonでディクショナリの要素数の出現回数をカウントし、一覧として出力したいのですが、
どういったコードを書けばよいでしょうか？(ダメ元ですが以下のコートを書いてみました）

```
p=partition
for v in max(partition.values()):
    l=list(p.values()).count(v)
```

pのデータは以下ような感じになっております。例えば「0」に該当するものがいくつあるのか知りたいです。

```
{'あんこ': 0, 'チョコ': 0, '飴': 0, 'クッキー': 0, 'お刺身': 2, '小麦粉': 1, 'てんぷら粉': 1, 'ちくわ': 2, 'マシュマロ': 0, '肉じゃが': 2,
```

Answer (score 1):

愚直に「value が 0 となる個数を数える」やり方です：

```
sum([1 for v in p.values() if v == 0])
```

ジェネレーターとして書いたり、`True` が `1` として扱われるのを援用したりすることもできます：

```
sum(v == 0 for v in p.values())
```

色んな value について何回も数えるなら、[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) が便利です：

```
from collections import Counter

cp = Counter(p.values())
cp[0]
```

参考： [count the number of occurrences of a certain value in a dictionary in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48371856/5989200) -- 英語版 Stack Overflow

Comment: 情報が取れました！有難うございます。抽出したリストもcp2=sorted(cp.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)で出現数宇の大きい順にすることが出来ました。

Comment: 良かったです :)　もしよければ、回答横のチェックマークを押して回答を承認することもできます。